# Does Spring Servlet Application Context stop a Camel ProducerTemplate when the Spring context is destroyed?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have a Spring Servlet Application Context with the following XML:

```
...
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camelContext">
    <contextScan />
    <template id="aProducerTemplate" />
</camelContext>
...
```

And the usage like so:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate aProducerTemplate;   
    ...
```

Since the producer template is a managed bean in the Spring Servlet Application Context will it call `aProducerTemplate.start()` when the Spring application context is initialized and call `aProducerTemplate.stop()` when the application context is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Servlet Application Context will start all beans including `CamelContext`.
`ProducerTemplate` belongs to `CamelContext` and will be started by Camel as part of camel context start procedure.

Therefore `ProducerTemplate` will be initialized and started when you access it in `MyService`.